# Paypal IPN notifications - MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

When i set up recurring payment, i put `MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS = 3 attempts`.

So After skipping 3 transactions, the profile will be `canceled` or `suspended` ?

And this action will be performed automatically by paypal or i must use

`ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus method` to change the status of

recurring payment profile ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When the profile payment is skipped 3 times it will automatically set the profile to suspended.  This would allow you to later collect the outstanding balance and then reactivate the profile.